# Data not inserting or updating after delete table in room DB Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to clear the database on the logout button click.
FlatDatabase class

```
@Database(entities = {SocietyFlatsDetailsData.class},version = 1)
public abstract class FlatDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
public static FlatDatabase instance;
public abstract FlatDao flatDao();

public static synchronized FlatDatabase getInstance(Context context){
    if (instance==null){
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext()
                ,FlatDatabase.class,"flat_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }
    return instance;
   }
}
```

I'm clearing data by this line

```
FlatDatabase.getInstance(getContext()).clearAllTables();
```

after executing this line table data is clear successfully. but the problem is data are not inserting when I'm trying to insert after delete table data.
it might be because of schema change
any solution ??

Comment: You are using a Singleton pattern, so you DB is only created once. Try to put "instance = null;" in your clearAllTables() method. This will cause a recreation of the DB on the next getInstance() call.

Comment: @gioravered clearAllTable() is predefine method. how can i put  "instance = null;"?

Comment: Oh sorry. was not familiar with it. In that case I'm not sure what the problem is..